# How to create a webserver with soft access point in CircuitPython?

Tags: webserver, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

I want to serve a basic index.html file using a Raspberry Pi Pico W. I am able to in MicroPython but need to use CircuitPython for this project. I found [code to create a soft access point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75577610/cant-set-up-soft-access-point-in-circuitpython) but wasn't able to create a webserver using it:

```
# import wifi module
import wifi

# set access point credentials
ap_ssid = "myAP"
ap_password = "password123"

# You may also need to enable the wifi radio with wifi.radio.enabled(true)

# configure access point
wifi.radio.start_ap(ssid=ap_ssid, password=ap_password)

"""
start_ap arguments include: ssid, password, channel, authmode, and max_connections
"""

# print access point settings
print("Access point created with SSID: {}, password: {}".format(ap_ssid, ap_password))

# print IP address
print("My IP address is", wifi.radio.ipv4_address)
```

I tried to add a webserver:

```
import wifi
import socketpool

# Set access point credentials
ap_ssid = "myAP"
ap_password = "password123"

# Configure access point
wifi.radio.start_ap(ssid=ap_ssid, password=ap_password)

# Print access point settings
print("Access point created with SSID: {}, password: {}".format(ap_ssid, ap_password))
print("My IP address is", wifi.radio.ipv4_address)

# Create a socket pool
pool = socketpool.SocketPool(wifi.radio)

# Create a simple HTTP server function
def simple_http_server():
    server_socket = pool.socket()
    server_socket.bind((wifi.radio.ipv4_address, 80))
    server_socket.listen(1)

    print("Server is listening on {}:80".format(wifi.radio.ipv4_address))

    while True:
        print("Waiting for a connection...")
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print("Accepted connection from:", client_address)

        client_socket.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
        client_socket.send("<html>Hello, World!</html>\r\n")
        client_socket.close()

# Start the HTTP server
simple_http_server()
```

I get:

```
Access point created with SSID: myAP, password: password123
My IP address is None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 36, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 21, in simple_http_server
TypeError: can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason that is happening is because `wifi.radio.ipv4_address` only works if you connect to an existing AP. If you have your own AP, you need to use `wifi.radio.ipv4_address_ap`.

> `ipv4_address: ipaddress.IPv4Address`
> IP v4 Address of the station when connected to an access point. None otherwise. (read-only)
> `ipv4_subnet_ap: ipaddress.IPv4Address`
> IP v4 Address of the access point subnet, when enabled. None otherwise. (read-only)
> <sub>https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/wifi/index.html#wifi.Radio</sub>

Here's the updated code:

```py
import wifi
import socketpool

# Set access point credentials
ap_ssid = "myAP"
ap_password = "password123"

# Configure access point
wifi.radio.start_ap(ssid=ap_ssid, password=ap_password)

# Print access point settings
print("Access point created with SSID: {}, password: {}".format(ap_ssid, ap_password))
print("My IP address is", str(wifi.radio.ipv4_address_ap))

# Create a socket pool
pool = socketpool.SocketPool(wifi.radio)

# Create a simple HTTP server function
def simple_http_server():
    server_socket = pool.socket()
    server_socket.bind((str(wifi.radio.ipv4_address_ap), 80))
    server_socket.listen(1)

    print("Server is listening on {}:80".format(wifi.radio.ipv4_address))

    while True:
        print("Waiting for a connection...")
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print("Accepted connection from:", client_address)

        client_socket.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
        client_socket.send("<html>Hello, World!</html>\r\n")
        client_socket.close()

# Start the HTTP server
simple_http_server()
```

**Note:** Make sure you convert `wifi.radio.ipv4_address_ap` into a string before using it, or you'll get this error: `TypeError: can't convert 'Address' object to str implicitly`